# Read a character followed by n number of integers like A 1 2 3 using Java's Scanner(System.in) object from the same line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am unable to read A 1 2 3 from the same line, 1 2 3 can be read from one line but because of A in the start, scanner only reads A.

```
String command = "";
int numbers;
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
command = scan.next();

while (scan.hasNextInt())
{
    numbers = scan.nextInt();
    ints.add(numbers);

}
scan.close();
```

Comment: Are you wanting `A` to be treated as `65`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, hasNextInt blocks because of the "infinite" nature of System.in... you could try calling nextLine and splitting on spaces...

Comment: Thanks, yes thats the solution as given by Frisch below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `nextLine()` (and `hasNextLine()`), split on one or more consecutive white-space characters (to create an array of tokens), set the `command` as the first token and then `Stream` the tokens - skip the first one (it's `command`) and collect to a `List`. Like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
    String command = tokens[0];
    List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(tokens).skip(1)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.printf("command = %s, ints = %s%n", command, ints.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! works perfectly the way I was hoping it will.